# Button not getting enabled after sending text to field in iOS devices web automation

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium, mobile-safari

I am automating a web app using appium with Java client. In my automation, I need to write text on a field, enabling the 'continue' button and press it.

Firstly, I tried using

```java
textField.sendKeys("text to send");
```

but it failed because, on iOS devices the 'continue' button was not getting enabled, I suppose the necessary events were not getting triggered to enable the button.

After some research, I ended up using Selenium Actions API. I created the following function

```java
public void enterTextField(String txt) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));            
   
    new Actions(getDriver())
              .sendKeys(getDriver().findElement(textField), txt)
              .perform();
}
```

The problem is that this function always throws StaleElementReferenceException even though I find the element every time I call this function.

I even added a wait beforehand ignoring StaleElementReferenceException.

Also, I tried to catch it and find the element again but same problem.

```java
public void enterTextField(String txt) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 
    Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));          
        
    try {
        new Actions(getDriver())
                .sendKeys(getDriver().findElement(textField), txt)
                .perform();
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            TestUtils.log().warn("Send keys to text field failed, retrying... {}", e.toString());
            new Actions(getDriver())
                    .sendKeys(getDriver().findElement(textField), txt)
                    .perform();
        }
    }
```

Any idea why this is happening? This is the first time I use selenium api directly, I usually automate native applications using appium java library instead.

Comment: Check if the "continue" button gets enabled after the text is written and the cursor changes focus. I had a case where i needed to add a click after setting the text for the "continue" button to get enabled. Maybe a SendKeys(keys.ENTER) will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately `sendKeys(Keys.Enter)` did not work, I even tried `Keys.BACK_SPACE` and `Keys.SEMICOLON` as well as changing focus. I believe in my case, the necessary events are not getting triggered and the textfield appears to be empty, even though it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, in my case, the button had the [disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) attribute, which was getting removed when the textfield was not empty.

So, what I did was to remove this property using javascriptExecutor, which lets me execute javascript code.

```java
public void enterTextField(String txt) throws InterruptedException {
    getDriver().findElement(textField).sendKeys("My Text");
    
    ((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled');",
                getDriver().findElement(continueButton));
    }
```